# Flutter : AdbConnectionClientInfo missing required field profileable

Tags: linux, flutter, dart

I just installed Android studio in ubuntu and started developing a flutter project and I keep getting this error in the console and it keeps repeating as well.

```
E/ppbrewery.clim(26412): AdbConnectionClientInfo missing required field profileable
E/ppbrewery.clim(26412): AdbConnectionClientInfo missing required field profileable
E/ppbrewery.clim(26412): AdbConnectionClientInfo missing required field profileable
```

Please help me out.

Comment: its help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62819826/problem-with-accessing-hidden-method-android-flutter-geolocator